# how to watch excel file changes in C#?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am developing to watch file changes , display notification and insert change list into listview.I have difficult that want to only changed notification if change attributes of excel file.Now if change excel attributes, display created, deleted, renamed notifications.
Could anyone suggest it to me?

Code:

```
string filepath = C:\New Folder;
private void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        sfilepath = e.FullPath.Substring(0, e.FullPath.Length - e.Name.Length - 1);
        if (sfilepath == filepath)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            DateTime lastWriteTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
            DateTime nowdt = DateTime.Now;
            if (lastWriteTime == nowdt)
            {                    
                this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "File " + e.ChangeType, e.FullPath, ToolTipIcon.Info);                                        
            }
        }
    }

    private void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        sfilepath = e.FullPath.Substring(0, e.FullPath.Length - e.Name.Length - 1);
        if (sfilepath == filepath)
        {
            this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "File " + e.ChangeType, e.FullPath, ToolTipIcon.Info);                                
        }
    }

    private void watcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        sfilepath = e.FullPath.Substring(0, e.FullPath.Length - e.Name.Length - 1);
        if (sfilepath == filepath)
        {
            this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "File " + e.ChangeType, e.FullPath, ToolTipIcon.Info);                               
        }
    }

    private void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        sfilepath = e.FullPath.Substring(0, e.FullPath.Length - e.Name.Length - 1);
        if (sfilepath == filepath)
        {
            this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1, "File Renamed", e.OldFullPath + " renamed to " + e.FullPath, ToolTipIcon.Info);                                
        }
    }
```

Change list:

```
New Microsoft Excel ワークシート.xls  2011/10/10 11:00:15 Created C:\New Folder
B1F38000                2011/10/10 11:00:55 Created C:\New Folder
New Microsoft Excel ワークシート.xls~RF83f213.TMP 2011/10/10 11:01:16 Created C:\New Folder
New Microsoft Excel ワークシート.xls  2011/10/10 11:01:16 Deleted C:\New Folder   
New Microsoft Excel ワークシート.xls  2011/10/10 11:01:16 Renamed C:\New Folder
New Microsoft Excel ワークシート.xls~RF83f213.TMP 2011/10/10 11:01:18 Deleted C:\New Folder
```

Comment: You can check the ChangeType of FileSystemEventArgs

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to watch just a specific folder, so your check against `filepath` is redundant.

Otherwise, do things much as you are currently, but check the filename of the file that triggers the events to see if it has `XLS`, `XLSX`, `XLSM` or any of the other Excel extensions on the file.